# How do I determine the time complexity of an algorithm when seemingly the constant does affect the complexity, when I was taught otherwise?

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Take this example: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000000lg10000000/lglg10000000%20%3E%205000%2a10000000)

If I have n*(lgn) / lg(lg(n))

compared against

5000n

No matter how high n goes, 5000n will always be higher. But if I took away the constant, the opposite would be true. But I always thought that constants multiplying were ignored in the grand scheme of things (5000n would just be considered n) which would lead to 5000n being considered smaller, when it seems to be bigger.

When asked which are worse time complexity algorithms, how do I answer?

Comment: Judging from that Wolfram|Alpha link, are you sure you meant to compare a constant to `5000n`, and not `n*logn/log log n` with `5000n`?

Comment: So you're comparing `f(n) = 5000n` to `g(n) = n * log(n) / log(log(n))`? `g` will be greater than `f` in the "long run", as `log(n) / log(log(n))` will be greater than `5000` eventually.

Comment: How do you dare to compare constant to linear function? linear function grows, while constant is constant.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, Meng. Blender, yes that's what I'm comparing.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified above. Typo on my part.

Comment: @DougSmith Alright, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to remember is that when people compare complexity, they almost always consider *asymptotic complexity*, which is to say, which is greater as `n` gets really big.

In this case, although `5000n > n*log n/ log log n` for basically any reasonable value of `n`, the latter still has the higher complexity.

Plugging in [`5000 < log n/ log log n`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5000+%3C+log+n%2F+log+log+n) got me an answer around `n = 2*10^23683` (click on "Approximate Forms"), and sure enough, `5000n < n*log n/ log log n` for [`n = 2*10^23683`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2a10%5E23683%2alog+2%2a10%5E23683%2F+log+log+2%2a10%5E23683+%3E+5000%2a2%2a10%5E23683+).

Comment: Is this true even for something such as this? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283%2F2%29%5E1000000+%3E+2%5E%281000000%2F2%29

Comment: And what does the first Wolfram|Alpha query signify?

Comment: The first query was how I got the value of `n`, and the second query is to confirm that `5000n < n*log n/ log log n` for that value of `n`.

Comment: Also, for the second Wolfram|Alpha link; those happen to meet at `n = 0`, and the equality will be true for any positive `n`. So, in this case (barring some constant factor on each function), `(3/2)^n` will be the greater value for usable values of `n` *as well as* when `n` gets large. Hence, it does have the higher complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Constant multipliers are deliberately ignored in asymptotic complexity analysis. For analysis of algorithms, in the abstract, it would be very difficult to count them - they depend on practical aspects of computer behavior that change with time.

For picking an algorithm, asymptotic complexity is only one measure to consider. It is also important to estimate or measure the actual time for expected problem sizes. Asymptotic complexity gives a warning if the algorithm is going to get drastically slower as the problem size increases.